# how can I install office 365 in this situation?

Tags: windows, script, office365

I have already office 2013 installed in my home PC, and I am trying to install office 365 and it keeps failing, Is there is any script to uninstall office 2013 and any later versions but in silent mode? anyone had a problem like that?

Comment: Failing how? What is the error shown?

Comment: couldn't install because office applications are already installed on this computer

Comment: Why can't you uninstall the 2013 version via control panel or Add/remove programs? Why is a script important?

Comment: I tried this step to uninstall from the Add/remove programs but no way, I need a script to force uninstall any existing old office applications before installing office 365 or if you have any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a xml file, then enter the following (replace ProPlus with your ProductID):

```
<Configuration Product="ProPlus">

<Display Level="none" CompletionNotice="no" SuppressModal="yes" AcceptEula="yes" />

</Configuration>
```

2. From the command line, run this command from the directory where the setup file is located:

```
setup.exe /uninstall ProPlus /config yourcreatedfile.xml
```

Replace `yourcreatedfile.xml` with the filename from step 1.

If the uninstall is still unsuccessful, download and install the Microsoft [Support and recovery assistant](https://aka.ms/SaRA-officeUninstallFromPC) tool, then follow the instructions.

Source: [Setup command-line options reference for Office 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-2013-resource-kit/cc178956(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#BKMK_config)